# Text being Auto-clipped

Tags: support, status-bydesign

When I respond to some Excel questions, I sometimes want to instruct the poster to:  *"Hi-light the cells you wish to process and run this short macro:"* 
Something in the input processor strips out the *"Hi-"*

I understand the reason for this, but I want to escape this feature if I intend *"Hi-"* to be something other than an abbreviation for *"Hello"*

Comment: Sounds like a problem with auto-correct in your browser? Presumably you can undo it when it happens?

Comment: Maybe don't use a hyphen?

Comment: @Alex I would guess it's actually on SO's side, they remove text like "hi" when they think they've identified it.

Comment: Oh, really? Anyhow, the correct spelling of the word is "highlight".

Comment: [status-bydesign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/158100)

Comment: Pick something a bit more English and less greety.  Llke "Select".  Or prefix "You can"

Comment: @HansPassant - I will take you advice.

Comment: The word is spelled "highlight." Not "hilight," and certainly never "hi-light."